# ionic cordova build android --prod --release shows Error: The Angular AoT build failed

Tags: ionic3

In my Ionic3 example I have properly executed

```
ionic cordova build --release android
```

But

```
ionic cordova build android --prod --release
```

generates following error..

```
C:\Users\JOHN\Demo>ionic cordova build android --prod --release
Running app-scripts build: --prod --platform android --target cordova
[09:20:02]  build prod started ...
[09:20:03]  clean started ...
[09:20:03]  clean finished in 11 ms
[09:20:03]  copy started ...
[09:20:03]  deeplinks started ...
[09:20:03]  deeplinks finished in 485 ms
[09:20:03]  ngc started ...
[09:20:20]  typescript error
        Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Expression 
form not supported (position 97:18 in the
        original .ts file), resolving symbol AppModule in 
C:/Users/JOHN/Demo/src/app/app.module.ts

Error: The Angular AoT build failed. See the issues above
at C:\Users\JOHN\Demo\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\aot\aot-
compiler.js:237:55
at step (C:\Users\JOHN\Demo\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\aot\aot-
compiler.js:32:23)
at Object.next (C:\Users\JOHN\Demo\node_modules\@ionic\app-
scripts\dist\aot\aot-compiler.js:13:53)
at fulfilled (C:\Users\JOHN\Demo\node_modules\@ionic\app-
scripts\dist\aot\aot-compiler.js:4:58)
[09:20:20]  copy finished in 17.55 s
```

I am really stuck here.. Any help is appreciated....

The New error after npm i

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10240
npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "i"
npm ERR! node v6.9.4
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! path C:\Users\JOHN\Demo\node_modules.staging\tsickle-87d2a783
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! syscall rename

npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Users\JOHN\Demo\node_modules.staging\tsickle-87d2a783' -> 'C:\Users\JOHN\Demo\node_modules\tsickle'
npm ERR!     at destStatted (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\install\action\finalize.js:25:7)
npm ERR!     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:264:29
npm ERR!     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Users\JOHN\Demo\node_modules.staging\tsickle-87d2a783' -> 'C:\Users\JOHN\Demo\node_modules\tsickle'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Users\JOHN\Demo\node_modules.staging\tsickle-87d2a783' -> 'C:\Users\JOHN\Demo\node_modules\tsickle'
npm ERR!     at destStatted (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\install\action\finalize.js:25:7)
npm ERR!     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:264:29
npm ERR!     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Users\JOHN\Demo\node_modules.staging\tsickle-87d2a783' -> 'C:\Users\JOHN\Demo\node_modules\tsickle'
npm ERR!     at Error (native) parent: 'Demo' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\JOHN\Demo\npm-debug.log

Comment: You can try after deleting `node_modules` folder. Then `npm i`

Comment: It generates npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10240..

Comment: What is the full error?

Comment: I have updated error above

Comment: It seems permission issue. `Please try running this command again as root/Administrator`

Comment: I am already running this command again as root/Administrator..

Comment: I think you need to log this here (https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/new) with a minimum working project where they can generate above error.

Comment: did you resolve it, i am stuck in similar situation

Comment: One way was to solve using --aot=false
But that too is not working for me